# Winforms Open Last Closed Form

Tags: winforms

How do i Re-Open Previously Closed Form.

Like I have Form 1 and Form 2 and Form 3

Previously I have opened Form 1 and 2 and Closed them

then How do i track that previously i have Closed Form 1 and Form 2

anyone who face similar issue and have the solution please Help....

Comment: Stack Object would be static if you want to do on more than one form

Stack<Object> objStack = new Stack<Object>();

push Filled object of form in the stack
objStack.Push(this);
this.Close()

when open pop the form objct typecast it and open the form

Use ShowDialog() Method because the Show() Method cannot access the disposed object of the Form..

Form frm = (Form)objStack.Pop();
frm.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this task by subscribing on "OnClose" event and saving information about this form into Closed Forms Stack. When you need to re-open recently closed form, you just pop the your stack and create just gotten form. Hope it will help, if you need I can provide a code sample.

Comment: I have Got u but can you please put some code for better clarification
with how to store information of form into the stack..

Comment: You can do this by saving form name (the easiest way) and by saving reference to the form, but in this case you shouldn't close forms but just hide them.